# How to echo from database in session?

Tags: php, mysql, database, session, select

I have problem with PHP $_SESSION.

I see only "username" in index page after successfull login/register.
When I change $_SESSION['username'] to $_SESSION['password'] is also displayed.

I need to display "points" value, which is not defined by user during login/register (5 points is auto added to user after register)

How to echo values from database, which are not inserted by users?

````
    if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

        if (empty($username)) {
            array_push($errors, "Please write username");
        }
        if (empty($password)) {
            array_push($errors, "Please write password");
        }

        if (count($errors) == 0) {
            $password = md5($password);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
            $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['success'] = "Logged in ";
                header('location: index.php');
            }else {
                array_push($errors, "Something went wrong");
            }
        }
    }```
````

Comment: How did you echo the session in your index.php?

Comment: I use that ```<?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
   <p>Hello <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?></strong></p>
   <p> <a href="index.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">Logout</a> </p>
  <?php endif ?>```

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. _“How to echo values from database, which are not inserted by users?”_ - same way as you would do with values that _were_ inserted by the user …? What difference does it make, how data got _into_ the database, when you are talking about reading data _from_ it here?

Comment: I mean get the "points" value of user, which is auto inserted after register. Sorry maybe I can't perfectly explain it, but the accepted answer working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with :

```
...
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
   $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

   //check the data you get from the BD
   var_dump($row);die; 
   // you'll get an array with you data where you'll find the points
   // then just assign it to a session

   $_SESSION['user_points'] = $row['user_points']; // for example

   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
   $_SESSION['success'] = "Logged in ";
   header('location: index.php');
}
...
```

Comment: Yes this working, but now I get "```array(1) { ["points"]=> string(1) "5" } ```"

Comment: Okay okay, working perfectly, i forgot to // the var dump :D Thanks bro, have a nice day!!